# how do i get the innerhtml from a dropdown option with php

Tags: php, html

I want to get the text in the `<option>` of my html code with php (to put inside a database) but the only thing I can fetch is my value.

html code:

```
<form method="post" action="{{PHP_SELF}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <select name="topics" id="topics" >
        <option value="0">Choose &hellip;</option>
        <option value="1">topic1</option>
        <option value="2">topic2</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

php code: (results in 1,2 but want topic1 or topic2)

```
$topic = isset($_POST['topics']) ? $_POST['topics'] : '';
```

is it possible to get this innerhtml code or should i change the values? Thank you.

Comment: `<option value="topic1">topic1</option>` or create an array of associated values to match it up.

Comment: Yeah, was thinking of doing the same, but wonderd if there was another way to fetch the innerhtml, the app also uses databases, so should i use an array or make another database table specifically for the options?

Comment: PHP only gets what the browser sends to it. The browser sends only the values for the form elements, not the rest of the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Your browser just sends the value of that field across the wire.

What you could do is:

- Use the same as value as you use as title (see comment by @Blake)
- Keep the list in PHP as well and read your text from there - like following:

  ```
  $values = array(1 => 'topic1', 2 => 'topic2');
  $topicName = $values[$_POST['topics']];
  ```

But you can't get stuff in PHP, that is not sent to the server. You can analyze what's sent from and to the server by opening the developer-tools in your browser.